# counting characteres in string using object

Tags: javascript, string, object, if-statement, counting

I'm trying to count the characters in a string using an object. This is the function that I wrote:

```
function maxChar(str) {

    let obj = {}   

    for(let char of str){
        if(obj[char]){
            obj[char] += 1 
        }           
        obj[char] = 1            
    }  
    console.log(obj)
}
```

When I run the function with the string "Hello There!" it returns:

```
{
   : 1,
  !: 1,
  e: 1,
  H: 1,
  h: 1,
  l: 1,
  o: 1,
  r: 1,
  T: 1
}
```

Which of course is not counting properly. If I change the if statement like this:

```
function maxChar(str) {

    let obj = {}   

    for(let char of str){
        if(!obj[char]){
            obj[char] = 1           
        }           
        obj[char] += 1      
    }  
    console.log(obj)
}
```

It returns

```
{
   : 2,
  !: 2,
  e: 4,
  H: 2,
  h: 2,
  l: 3,
  o: 2,
  r: 2,
  T: 2
}
```

Are not tboth functions supposed to do the same? why is this happening?

Comment: In your first example `obj[char] = 1` will always run, even after you have incremented your value, resetting it to 1. You can put this in an `else`

Comment: The first version would need an `else` so it doesn't reset the count to 1 after incrementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version looks like this.  I've added some comments:

```
    for(let char of str){
        if(obj[char]){
            obj[char] += 1  // this happens only when the `if` condition is met
        }           
        obj[char] = 1 // this happens all the time, regardless of the `if` condition
    }
```

That version will always reset the character count to 1.  Even if it had just briefly incremented the count to 2, it will still reset it to 1 immediately after having done so.

One fix (that most closely matches your original code) could be:

```
    for(let char of str){
        if(obj[char]){
            obj[char] += 1
        } else {
            obj[char] = 1
        }
    }
```